# The password on this account cannot be changed at this time?

Tags: active-directory, group-policy, password-management, password-reset, password-policy

A user in my company forgot his password and I had to reset it to a temporary one. I checked the box that says "*User Must Change Password at Next Logon*".

When he logged on and entered the temporary password and two times his newly chosen password and confirmed, an error message popped up saying: "**The password on this account cannot be changed at this time.**"

Looking at our group policy settings (see below), I assume it has to do with the *minimum password age*. I have the *minimum password age* set to 90 days, so a user who is forced to change his password cannot immediately revert the change to his old password. **But how do I deal with the process of resetting a users password then, if the user is unable to change it to a permanent one within the *minimum password age* period?**

```
C:\>net accounts
Force user logoff how long after time expirest?:          Never
Minimum password age (days):                              90
Maximum password age (days):                              365
Minimum password length:                                  7
Length of password history maintained:                    4
Lockout threshold:                                        5
Lockout duration (minutes):                               10
Lockout observation windows (minutes):                    5
Computer role:                                            WORKSTATION
The command completed successfully.
```

Comment: Are these settings from `Default Domain Policy` or another GPO?

Comment: Those are the settings that are currently active in the domain. It is not important from where they come. But anyway, *yes*, they are from the default domain policy.

Comment: Well, if `User Must Change Password at Next Logon` is set this behaviour should not occur. References: [Technet1](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh994570%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) So maybe it is not the Minimum password age.

Answer (score 4):

The minimum password age only affect the users ability to "change" their own password. It does not affect admins or account operators from being able to "reset" someone else's password. The "must change at next logon" does an override on the minimum password value, because after an admin does a reset, you want the user to choose a new password.

Is your problem particular to that one user? Suspect there is a strange or bad ACL on that user. Check to see that their account has: Self / Change Password / Allow, and that there are no Change Password / Deny ACLs.

[image]

Comment: "does an override on the minimum password value". In fact, it literally sets the pwdLastSet attribute to (never) so that the check against minimum password age always passes.

Comment: @RyanBolger - nice! I didn't know the mechanics of how that worked

Comment: Yep, the attribute is an integer and technically gets set to 0, but the GUI shows it as "(never)".